# What is another word for kilt?

Tags: synonyms, american-english

It seems to me that some Americans will say hoop.

[image]

Comment: fillibeg or philibeg

Comment: "Kilt" is pretty much it, if you wish to avoid "skirt".

Comment: When referring to the wearing of a traditional kilt by men, it is called a “kilt”. In the US, I have never heard it called a hoop when referring to menswear. Although, a distinction is usually made between traditional dress kilts and modern working, workwear, cargo, utility, or tactical kilts.